# Trustpilot invitation api weird result

Tags: trustpilot

Trying to create invitations using their API, I get a proper result back, however the status is "notsent". There is zero debug information to go by, so I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this and might have ideas for fixing the issue.

Here's an example of a response I got from their api:

```
    {
    "businessUnitId": "<business unit id here>",
    "businessUserId": "<business user id here>",
    "createdTime": "2018-10-02T09:58:35.135569Z",
    "id": "<invitation id here>",
    "locale": "da-DK",
    "preferredSendTime": "2018-10-09T09:58:34Z",
    "recipient": {
        "email": "<email goes here>",
        "name": "<name goes here>"
    },
    "redirectUri": "http://trustpilot.com",
    "referenceId": "<our ref id>",
    "replyTo": "trustpilot@boozt.com",
    "sender": {
        "email": "noreply.invitations@trustpilotmail.com",
        "name": "Booztlet.com"
    },
    "sentTime": null,
    "source": "InvitationApi",
    "status": "notsent",
    "tags": [],
    "templateId": "57cfc1a660e1cc0620b53a38"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the NotSent status code is expected for new invitations. This is because invitations are sent asynchronously - at around the time you put in as your "preferredSendTime".

If you login to your account at https://businessapp.b2b.trustpilot.com/#/invitations/invitation-history, you should be able to see the invitation you created, and whether it was sent or not (since you specified October 9th as your preferredSendTime, the invitation will still be queued until that point)

Comment: Yeah, I realized my stupidity later on, when I actually read what the preferredSendTime had. It makes very good sense that the invitation is not sent yet, as it was scheduled seven days in the future.

Would have been nice if they had chosen "scheduled" as status code instead. Or just documented the possible results of the call.